# How can I put data into my jdbc table using a variable?

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I want to store into my variable var1 the information that the user puts. The user writes his name and var1 gets it from the textfield using getText().
This information I want to store it every time my program executes in my database table.I am trying this code. Please help me.

```
            public void database(){
  String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
      String username = "";
  String password = "";

 Connection conn = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs=null;


 try {
   // Step 1 - Load driver
      // Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); // Class.forName() is not 
      needed 
since JDBC 4.0

  // Step 2 - Open connection
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

       // Step 3 - Execute statement
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
         stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO players (name,fitore) VALUES 
    (var1,0)");

     } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

And it gives me this error.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "var1" does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons this isn't working.

First, var1 is a set of characters in a string literal, it has no connection to any variable in your code.

Second, because 'var1' in your sql call isn't inside quotations it is looking for a var1 column to grab a value from.

Use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of a Statement, it will update your sql string with parameters from your code.

Use `?` in your SQL string where you want to insert values from a  variable, and one of  the .setType(index, value) functions of the PreparedStatement object to set the values of those ?'s in the order that they appear. Note that index starts at ONE and not at ZERO.

It's also more secure, since you're taking user input you don't want to use plain old Statement, it creates a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

1. use java.sql.PreparedStatement instead of Statement, it is sql injections save.
2. use sql statement like `INSERT INTO players (name,fitore) VALUES (?,?)`
3. set params via statement methods:

   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY_CREATE);

   pstmt.setString(1, var1);

   pstmt.setInt(2, 0);